# Reporting services error if I try to run report online

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a report with Reporting Services, in my local pc it works. But if I try to run it on Internet Explorer, I have this error message:

```
Errore durante l'elaborazione del report. (rsProcessingAborted)
Query execution failed for dataset 'chartArea_monthly'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
Per ulteriori informazioni su questo errore, navigare al server di report nel server locale oppure abilitare gli errori remoti.
```

I have see that the error is in the query that populated my chart. The query is this:

```
--Modified by Somosree Banerjee (IBM) for SRQ00409010 on 11-15-2011
-- NOTE: it is strongly recommended to use MS SQL Server Management studio (copy + paste) to edit this query
--CREATED ON Michele Castriotta
use iMELReporting
DECLARE @TemporaryTable TABLE 
                        (
                        Mese NVARCHAR(2),
                        Year NVARCHAR(100),
                        Value DECIMAL(12,5),
                        Target1 DECIMAL(12,5),
                        Target2 DECIMAL(12,5),
                        Target3 DECIMAL(12,5),
                        Target4 DECIMAL(12,5),
                        Target DECIMAL(12,5)
                        )

-- Get PO start and end time and the linkupID
DECLARE @DATA_START AS DATETIME
DECLARE @DATA_END AS DATETIME

DECLARE @Date as DATETIME
SET @Date = '2015-2-1'
DECLARE @ProductionLine AS NVARCHAR(100)
SET @ProductionLine = 'COMBINER001'

--THE USER SELECT A DATE, I SET THE DATA IN THE FIRST DAY OF 3 mounth before this data
--THE CURRENT MONTH IS NOT CALCULATED
SET @DATA_START = DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,DATEADD(MM,-3,@Date)),0)
--THE USER SELECT A DATE, I SET THE DATA IN THE FIRST DAY OF 1 mounth before this data
--THE CURRENT MONTH IS NOT CALCULATED
SET @DATA_END = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,DATEADD(MM,-1,@Date)),0) - DAY(DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,DATEADD(MM,-1,@Date)),0)) + 1) -1
SET @DATA_END =DATEADD(second,86399,@DATA_END) 
--THE USER SELECT A DATE, I SET THE DATA IN THE LAST DAY OF WEEK

--SELECT @DATA_START,@DATA_END


INSERT INTO @TemporaryTable (Mese,Year,Value,Target1,Target2,Target3,Target4,Target)
SELECT 
    --DATENAME(MONTH,MONTH(k.Data)),
    MONTH(k.Data),
    YEAR(k.Data),
    AVG(k.Value) * 100,
    t.Red,
    t.Yellow,
    t.Lime,
    t.CornflowerBlue,
    target
FROM 
    KPI_Value k LEFT JOIN [iMELReporting].[dbo].[Target] t
    ON (k.Machine = t.Machine AND k.KPI = t.KPI)
WHERE
    k.KPI = 3 AND
    k.Machine = @ProductionLine AND
    k.Data BETWEEN @DATA_START AND @DATA_END
    AND t.DataStart <= k.Data AND t.DataEnd >= k.Data 
GROUP BY 
    --DATENAME(mONTH,MONTH(k.Data)),
    MONTH(k.Data),
    YEAR(k.Data),
    t.Red,
    t.Yellow,
    t.Lime,
    t.CornflowerBlue,
    t.target
ORDER BY 
    YEAR(k.Data),
    MONTH(k.Data)


SELECT [dbo].[AF_GetNameOfMonth] (Mese),Year,Value,Target1,Target2,Target3,Target4,Target FROM @TemporaryTable
```

The problem is in the last SELECT if I try tu delete this command

```
SELECT [dbo].[AF_GetNameOfMonth] (Mese),Year,Value,Target1,Target2,Target3,Target4,Target FROM @TemporaryTable
```

and insert this:

```
SELECT Mese,Year,Value,Target1,Target2,Target3,Target4,Target FROM @TemporaryTable
```

I don't have any problem. So this is the code of my function:

```
USE [iMELReporting]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[AF_GetNameOfMonth]    Script Date: 01/16/2015 09:32:31 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO



ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[AF_GetNameOfMonth](@Month [INT])
RETURNS NVARCHAR(100)
AS 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @monthName as NVARCHAR(100);
        SELECT @monthName =
        CASE @Month
            WHEN 1 then 'January'  
            WHEN 2 then 'February' 
            WHEN 3 then 'March'
            WHEN 4 then 'April' 
            WHEN 5 then 'May' 
            WHEN 6 then 'June'
            WHEN 7 then 'July' 
            WHEN 8 then 'August' 
            WHEN 9 then 'September' 
            WHEN 10 then  'October'
            WHEN 11 then 'November' 
            WHEN 12 then 'December' 
        END
        RETURN @monthName

    END
```

If I try to run this original report in my local pc it works, but if I try to run it online I have that error and if I delete the function of my SP also online the report works. Where is my error please?

Comment: You need to check if the online report server has access to that function this error generates when database is unable to populate the resultset.

Comment: How can I verify it?

Comment: Check the database which is getting hit by online report and see that function exists there and the user under which the ssrs tool is running has access to that function

Comment: Ok thanks I have checked and the Report user don't had a permission for execute that funciton. Now works. THanks

Comment: I am going to add that as answer please accept it so question will be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the online report server has access to that function this error generates when database is unable to populate the result set. Check the database which is getting hit by online report and see that function exists there and the user under which the `SSRS` tool is running has access to that function

Answer (score 0):

This is very commonly observed problem that people runs into. I had this problem many a times when I used to work on SSRS reports.

When you run report on your local machine then it uses the Database which is installed on your machine (of course you select the database while configuring report). But when you deploy this report on LIVE server, then you forget to change the Database configuration. In turn, when report server makes a call to report, then that report tries to connect with the database which was configured at design time. Since that Database is not available on LIVE server, your report fails to execute.

On LIVE server you may have a database with the same name, but following two things varies between local machine and LIVE machine.

1. User DB credential
2. Database IP

So, in order to avoid this problem, make sure that before you GO LIVE, change these things in your report.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if user has permissions to execute function. This can happen in case of no permission to execute few database obkects like stored procedures or functions.